# Python/Flask : Is there a way generate a password prompt instead of making a whole user plateform?

Tags: python, flask

i'm trying to do a basic blog to display what i'm working on.

I was currently making a invisible route to make post directly onto it so i don't need to update my blog everytime i finish a new project, and created a ghost "post" page.

Still, somebody could find the link and i'd like to put some kind of password prompt to validate the post method, is there a way to do that without making a whole login/user system ? (Like using @login_required and all)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use Flask BasicAuth. You won't need a database as you will only add one user right where you config the app, like so:

```
from flask_basicauth import BasicAuth

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME'] = 'john'
app.config['BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD'] = 'matrix'

basic_auth = BasicAuth(app)

@app.route('/secret')
@basic_auth.required
def secret_view():
    return render_template('secret.html')
```

Then you would simply add the "@basic_auth.required" decorator to your "post" route. Alternatively, you could simply name the route something that cannot be guessed, like a random string of characters.

more BasicAuth info [here](https://flask-basicauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)